# Count of groups

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a count of groups in mysql?

For example I have 4 rows

cat1
cat2
cat1
cat3

I would like a count of categories, i.e 3

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct(cat)) from table;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, seems simple now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "purest" answer, but you could do this with a nested select query

select count(*) from (
select catagory, count(*) from table_name
group by catagory) A

Answer (score 0):

Assume one table 'table5' with column name 'colname'

Script to create that table is given below

```
CREATE TABLE `table5` (
    `colname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Assume it contain data as given below

[image]

To get count of each name use following query

```
select colname,count(*)as count from table5 group by colname;
```